# How to save the state of the TreeView after closing the form?

Tags: c#, winforms

On the form is located "TreeView".
Node_1
- Node_1_1
- Node_1_2
Node_2
- Node_2_1
- Node_2_2

**Session 1**
User opens form
Result:
- "Node_1" - collapsed; ("+")
- "Node_2" - collapsed; ("+")

The user expands "Node_2".
Result:
- "Node_1" - collapsed; ("+")
- "Node_2" - expanded; ("-")
Closes the form.

**Session 2**
User opens form
Result
"Node_1" - collapsed; ("+")
"Node_2" - expanded; ("-")

**Question.**
How to save the status of "minimized" ("+"), "maximized" ("-") for all nodes of all levels?

Comment: It is hard to make out what you are asking, but it sounds like you want user settings.

Comment: @NewContributor I tried to change the question.
I managed to make the question more understandable?